# Ionic 4/ 5 - Remove cached data, when i revisit the same screen again

Tags: angular, ionic4, ionic5

Once I entered the data on some screen X, while revisiting via `this.navCtrl.navigateForward`, older data gets retained, I need to clear up that data, I am not able to figure it out, I tried `replace_url:true` in navigationExtras object, as well as tried removing Ionic reroute strategy as well.

Here is the Ionic configuration

````
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.1
   @capacitor/core : 2.4.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : none
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (12 plugins total)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v10.22.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.14.6
   OS     : macOS Catalina```


 here is the image link
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/t363H.png
````

Comment: Could you please add some more details about that page and what's its content?

Comment: sure, i have a form page like this in this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/t363H.png, Now after proceeding with this page I move on to some other pages, using ionic `this.navCtrl.navigateForward`, now when i again revisit in this form page, the previous data remains there. I want to reinitialize that page as was happened in ionic 3, do tell, if its still unclear